# Count value inside object inside object

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I have an object within an object where I want to count the quantity and return the value.

Example:

```
cart: {items: {A {number: 'xxx', quantity: 1, price: 999}, B {number: 'xxx', quantity: 3, price: 999}, C {number: 'xxx', quantity: 2, price: 999} }}
```

What I now want is the return of the quantity count 6.

This is what I have achieved so far. How do I proceed?

```
function() {
  var value = {{DataWithInformations}}
  var itemCount = cart.items.quantity
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to go about it.

One of the cleanest would would probably be to use the `reduce` function:

```
data.cart.items.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.quantity, 0);
```

Written with ES5 (no arrow functions), it'd look like this:

```
data.cart.items.reduce(function (sum, item) { return sum + item.quantity }, 0);
```

(Note: What you posted isn't valid JSON or a valid object, so I made some guesses as to how the object actually is.

```js
const data = {
  cart: {
    items: [
      { quantity: 1 },
      { quantity: 2 },
      { quantity: 3 }
    ]
  }
};

const sum = data.cart.items.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.quantity, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

---

Update to go with the changed object in the question:

ES6:

```
Object.keys(a.cart.items).reduce((sum, key) => sum + a.cart.items[key].quantity, 0);
```

ES5:

```
Object.keys(a.cart.items).reduce(function (sum, key) { return sum + a.cart.items[key].quantity, 0);
```

```js
const a = {
  cart: {
    items: {
      A: {number: 'xxx', quantity: 1, price: 999}, 
      B: {number: 'xxx', quantity: 3, price: 999}, 
      C :{number: 'xxx', quantity: 2, price: 999} 
    }
  }
};

const result = Object.keys(a.cart.items).reduce((sum, key) => sum + a.cart.items[key].quantity, 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not that I see, though it won't work with the updated object you just posted. Gimme a sec and I'll have the code sample updated.

Comment: Oh, guess the update wasn't yours, but someone else interpreted your post differently. They were probably correct rather than my assumption.

Comment: `data.cart.items.reduce(function (sum, item) { return sum + item.quantity }, 0);`

Was exactly what i needed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reduce function to get the value out of your Array. PS: The data structure you have provided is not syntactically correct so I'm going to make a few assumptions.

```js
var data = {
  cart: {
    items: [{
        number: 'xxx',
        quantity: 1,
        price: 999
      },
      {
        number: 'xxx',
        quantity: 3,
        price: 999
      },
      {
        number: 'xxx',
        quantity: 2,
        price: 999
      }
    ]

  }
};

var qtySum = data.cart.items.reduce(function(mem, item) {
  mem += item.quantity;
  return mem;
}, 0);

console.log("Total count:", qtySum);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a solution:

```js
a = {cart:{items:{A:{number: 'xxx', quantity: 1, price: 999}, B: {number: 'xxx', quantity: 3, price: 999}, C :{number: 'xxx', quantity: 2, price: 999} }}};

sum=0;
for(key in a.cart.items){
  sum += a.cart.items[key].quantity;
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean ES6 solution:

```js
const cart = {
  items: {
    A: {number: 'xxx', quantity: 1, price: 999}, 
    B: {number: 'xxx', quantity: 3, price: 999}, 
    C :{number: 'xxx', quantity: 2, price: 999} 
  }
};

const total = Object.values(cart.items)
                    .map((obj) => obj.quantity)
                    .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over to the JSON and then add the `quantity`.

```
var jsonData = {'cart':
                    {'items': 
                                {
                'A':{'number': 'xxx', 'quantity': 1,'price': 999}, 
                'B' : {'number': 'xxx', 'quantity': 3, 'price': 999},
                'C':{'number': 'xxx', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 999}
                }
          }
        };
var keys = Object.keys(jsonData.cart.items);

var quantity = 0;
for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
   var key = keys[i];
   var item = jsonData.cart.items[key];
   quantity += item.quantity;
}

alert(quantity);
```

Here is the link to [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oxvfbenf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `for` loop for your problem.
I see you put a colon after `cart` so I guess your cart is in another JSON object.

```js
var foo = {
  cart: {
    items: {
      A: {number: 'xxx', quantity: 1, price: 999},
      B: {number: 'xxx', quantity: 3, price: 999},
      C: {number: 'xxx', quantity: 2, price: 999}
    }
  }
};

// This is what you need
document.getElementById("please-click-me").onclick = function() {
  var sum = 0;
  // Note that the 'in' gives you the keys, not the objects themselves
  for (var key in foo.cart.items) {
    sum += foo.cart.items[key].quantity;
  }
  alert(sum);
}
```

```html
<button id="please-click-me">Click</button>
```

Hope this helps :).